# django using futures in TamplateView issue

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to perform some unit of work in TemplateView asynchronously using concurrent.futures. However, I am running into issues where my async code is not getting invoked. Am I doing something wrong here?  This is a sample code which just multiplies a number, but in reality I want to copy some files in the background asynchronously. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import concurrent.futures
import time

class AsyncTest(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        op = kwargs.get('op')

        if op == 'asynch':
            print 'using futures async'
            executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
            # I see this print message
            print 'executing future 1 time'
            executor.map(self.load, 10)
            return render(request, 'text.html', {'lines':'Performing async processing!', 'op':op})
        else:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Operation not implemented at this time (op=%s)" % op)

    def load(x):
        #I never see this get invoked
        print 'in load...sleep'
        time.sleep(2)
        print 'sqr x*x=%s of x=%s' %((x*x), x)
        return x*x
```

I never see anything printed from the load method in the server, just the page renders with last thing printed: "executing future 1 time"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on trying to do do non-blocking processing using concurrent since it looks like that is not possible. I ended up switching to django-celery to do my async processing.

Answer (score 0):

How come you didn't try harder, this is a nice idea ! Stumbled on this question as I was looking if anyone tried futures with django.

I had to fix your example to try it : executor.map returns an iterator that isn't executed until you actually iterate it. And its second argument must be an iterable, such as a list. What can be done here is to pass the returned iterator to the template and have a for loop to actually render the result.

Now, celery is the way to go with django to handle parallel processing, so I agree with your second choice. On the other hand, `futures` being more focussed its syntax looks neater for that specific case.

Also, I suggest another alternative, that's what I'm usually doing in pages that are a bit slow because they aggregate information from several sources: have the view return a skeletton template with maybe the most useful information already displayed, then use javascript to load missing parts, that are loaded from other views. Classic frameworks like jQuery will help doing this in an imperative way, but angularjs is really worth checking for its declarative approach.

Comment: thanks for your insightful comment Vincent. I actually ended up using both django-celery and futures. I used celery for aync processing logic and then futures: ThreadPoolExecutor to prallel load multiple files into HDFS at the same time. I come from the Java world so python new to me so that giving up early was probably just frustration, anyhow I am beginning to dig python more and more.